# Find Element IDs of HTML TextBox

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to build a very basic C# Forms application that manipulates an online form. The downside is, the website is pretty old school.  I'm struggling to figure out how to 'point' to the textboxes of the website.

I'm trying to use:
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PanelMain")...

But getting Null errors.  When looking at the HTML of the site, its a lot of Divs inside Divs...  Is there a way to list the available objects / document elements I can use?

For example, use this website. https://miscm.callmis.com/.  How would I write the code to access the User Name text box to populate it with whatever string I want in C#?

I hope that makes sense - Thx

Comment: What library are you using to get at the HTML Dom in C#?

Comment: Not using any yet...

Comment: It looks like you are using a WebBrowser control in your forms app, you should be able to get at the elements from the Document property.  Here is an MSDN article describing that code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What I'm struggling to do though is find the right name for the element.  Its such ugly HTML that I don't know what element name it is...

Comment: If using GetElementById, in the example page provided the username textbox has an id of Login1_UserName. Try using the developer tools of the browser that you are using and this should allow you to click elements on the page and get direct access to the generated html and element properties, this will definitely help you through this process.

Comment: Developer Tools!!  That'll do it.  Thanks a bunch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66412/discussion-between-keynesiancross-and-mreyeros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do the following to get access to the Username textbox of the provided page:

```
 var userTextInput = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Login1_UserName");
```

For accessing the iframe and if it is the only IFRAME on the page, you can do the following:

```
 var userTextInput = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.GetElementById("Login1_UserName")
```

Comment: Thanks for that - that works.  Problem I'm now having though (the webpage behind that login), is the elemnt is in a iframe (I think this is the problem).   I can see the element in developer tools, but when I use the method above it comes back with a null expection.  Is there something special I have to do if its within an iframe